# What is `glue get-table` analog in trino?

Tags: amazon-web-services, hive, aws-glue, trino

[Trino](https://trino.io/) can connect to hive catalog (especially to glue catalog). But in aws glue there is a [command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/glue/get-table.html) `aws glue get-table` that output full table metadata - what about Trino? yes it has some [system tables](https://trino.io/docs/current/connector/system.html) but they mostly about catalogs, not individual tables.

Any idea how to get full table properties in trino?